# Missing \item error when centering sections in LaTeX

Tags: latex

So I am writing up a worksheet for my students to use and I wanted to just have a few numbered section headers like I have below. However, for some reason, the second set of centered title is returning the error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{center} at the end of the second \end{center}. Is there some way around this? I have even copy/pasted the first set of centerings just in case it was a syntax error of some sort.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \section{Solve using substitution}
\end{center}
\blah\blah\blah

\begin{center}
\section{Solve using substitution}
\end{center}
\blah\blah\blah
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\begin{center} ... \end{center}` should not be used for headers. In my opinion the best option is to use:

```
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
```

P.S. This will center ALL headers in the document, if that is what you were looking for this is the cleanest solution